# Vue payload data multiplies on click

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

So I've got a strange behavior happening. When I click to like a new post first time it likes increase by one when I click the second time it increases by two then by three then by four etc. Why is this happening?

This is my Vue method:

```
methods: {
  likePost(id) {
    this.likeNewPost(id).then(data => {
      if(data && data.success) {
        socket.emit('like-new-post');

        socket.on('like-new-post', () => {

          const post = {
            author: data.username,
            postID: data.postID,
            createdAt: data.createdAt
          }
          console.log(post);
          this.increaseLikeCount(post);
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

On first click `console.log(post)` shows me one post, then two posts then three. Why is this happening ?

Comment: socket.on add new listener. and it listen forever.  so when you click for the first time you create first listener. then another and another.  at the end of function all listeners still waits for new message.

Answer (score 0):

So this code solves the issue:

```
        socket.on('like-new-post', () => {
          this.increaseLikeCount(post).then(() => {
            socket.off('like-new-post')
          })
        });
```

`socket.off('like-new-post')` removes the listener and so on the next click there is only one post sent.